# Relatório usando array

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho uma tabela que tem 3 campos:

> id(PK)    id_(FK)   datas
>
> 1               1                       01/01/2015
>    2               1                       01/02/2015
>    3               2                       01/01/2015
>    4               2                       01/02/2015

Pois bem, possuo um relatório padrão onde tenho que imprimir da seguinte forma:

> NUM(seq)            Nome(busco da outra tabela)      data1                        data2
>
> 1                                José(FK-id->1)                                          01/01/2015       01/02/2015
>  
>    2                                João(FK-id->2)                                          01/01/2015         01/02/2015

Detalhe é que tenho de imprimir até 18 datas uma ao lado da outra. Caso haja mais de 18 datas para o mesmo id jogo para a linha de baixo, caso contrário pulo para o próximo id, como está acima.

Estou usando um *array* e só consegui imprimir uma linha em baixo da outra e repetindo o nome em todas elas. Como consigo fazer isso?

OBS: O relatório está funcionando, mas imprimindo uma linha em baixo da outra, só preciso mostrar como está descrito acima.

Comment: Mostre o código que já fez para que possamos ter uma ideia disso.

Comment: Qual banco você esta utilizando?

Answer (score 0):

Oque você pode fazer, é fazer um loop nessa array, agrupar por FK, depois fazer um loop na array já agrupada, em cada item retornado fazer um loop nas datas e exibir no relatório.